# How do I change column type in Python from int to object for sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am really new to Python and scikit-learn (sklearn) and I am trying to load this dataset which consists of 7 columns of attributes and 1 column of the data classification (class/data target). But there's this one attribute which consists of data [1,2,3,4,5] which actually marks a stage of something, thus making it a nominal, not numeric. But of course python recognizes it as a numerical data (int64), when in fact I want it to be treated as a nominal data (object). How do I change the column type to nominal?

I have done the following.

```
print(data.dtypes)
data["col_name"]=data["col_name"].astype(numpy.object)
print(data.dtypes)
```

In the first print, it still recognizes my data["col_name"] as an int64, but after the `astype` line, it has changed it `object`. But it doesn't make any difference to the data, since when I try to use `matplotlib` and create a histogram, it still recognizes both the X and Y as numbers instead of object.

Also I have read about the `One Hot Encoding` and `Label Encoding` on the documentation, but I figured they are not what I need in my case. I wonder if I have misunderstood something or maybe there's another solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Reading through the documents for sklearn.  This package has thorough documentation.  In particular the [Preprocessing section on encoding categorical features](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features):

In regards to keeping categorical features represented in an array of integers, ie `[1,2,3,4,5]`, we have this:

> Such integer representation can not be used directly with scikit-learn
>   estimators, as these expect continuous input, and would interpret the
>   categories as being ordered, which is often not desired (i.e. the set
>   of browsers was ordered arbitrarily). One possibility to convert
>   categorical features to features that can be used with scikit-learn
>   estimators is to use a one-of-K or one-hot encoding, which is
>   implemented in OneHotEncoder. This estimator transforms each
>   categorical feature with m possible values into m binary features,
>   with only one active.

So what you can to do is convert your array into 5 new columns (this case, since you have 5 possible values) using [one-hot encoding](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder.html#sklearn.preprocessing.OneHotEncoder).

Here is some working code.  The input is a column of categorical parameters `[1,2,3,4,5]`, the ouput is a matrix, 5 columns, 1 for each of the 5 possible choices:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]])  
OneHotEncoder(categorical_features='all', dtype='numpy.float64', handle_unknown='error', n_values='auto', sparse=True)
print enc.transform([[1],[2],[3],[4],[5]]).toarray()
```

Output:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]]
```

Say your categorical parameters were in this order: `[1,3,2,5,4,3,2,1,3,4,2]`.  You would get this output:

```
[[ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  0.  1.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 1.  0.  0.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  1.  0.  0.]
 [ 0.  0.  0.  1.  0.]
 [ 0.  1.  0.  0.  0.]]
```

So this 1 column will convert into 5 columns.

Comment: Hey sorry for the late reply,  i didn't notice I had a new answer. I wanted to try you solution, but then I discovered this `data['class'] = data['class'].astype(str)` already worked, python already recognizes the class column as a string (object). I think that's enough in my case, because it's a class, not an attribute. But I'll keep your solution in mind in case I have similar problem in the future. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
print(data.dtypes)
data["col_name"]=data["col_name"].astype(str)
print(data.dtypes)
```